# How to change Azure local deploy port - tcp to http?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

When I try to run Azure sdk, it throws me an error `Cannot launch the browser for URI tcp://127.0.0.1:81/ because it is not a web URI`. I understand that the TomcatWorkerRole running on port 81 but instead of using http or https to access the web site. The browser does not know how to handle the tcp:// prefix. How do I  change tcp:// to http://. Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to get the compute emulator to open the browser automatically for a TCP endpoint, and you do need to keep the endpoint TCP to get Tomcat working. You'll just need to open the browser yourself and browse to `http://127.0.0.1:81`. (You could even do `start http://127.0.0.1:81` from the command-line.)